# Mass Delete Reports Older Than a Specific Date

Tags: reporting, delete

I'm looking to mass delete reports that haven't run in the last ~20 months. Specifically, anything that hasn't been run since 01/01/2021. So, I've entered the following criteria in Mass Delete for reports:
[image]

However, when I go to execute the delete, I'm greeted with the following error:
[image]

I don't know what else to enter when my search string works in the search area but not in the actual execution of the delete, and the error message is basically useless.

Any thoughts from the community? Thanks much!

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please do not post code, error or other important text exclusively as screenshots - it is not as accessible to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology. (Plus it makes it harder for anyone to help if they want to copy anything locally.) Instead, copy your text and paste it in the SFSE editor - code with three backticks (```) above & below it in order to format it as a code block, and error text with a greater than symbol (>) & space at the beginning to format it as a quote block.

Comment: You might have to use yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dataloader for this purpose

Step 1. Extract reports WHERE LastRunDate < RequiredDate

- You should extract Ids of reports that will be deleted and save data to .csv

Step 2. Delete

- Open Dataloader and choose "Delete", under object selection select any (SF does not check Object type if delete by Id)
- select you csv and run

Hope this help

Comment: Will give it a try! Interesting that Mass Delete is an option, works for the date I enter, but then hits a bug when you try to execute it. Thanks,